# Listen to changes made by another application

Tags: mongoose

I've got two applications which are using the same mongo database and the same model/tabel. For example, both uses `mongoose.model('foo', schema)`.

- The first application manages the data: Adds, changes and removes entries at the model *foo*
- The second application just listens on the data: It uses the data of *foo*.

The second application needs to know if the data of *foo* has changed. When I look at the documentation of mongoose, I just found the middlewares for `save` and `remove`. But when I'm add post hooks to the schema, they aren't triggered at the second application.

When I search generally for change hooks at mongo database, I mainly find information that is a few years old and says that MongoDB doesn't support triggers. An alternative is to listen to the oplog. But about oplog I found nothing on the mongoose page.

What is the best practice to achieve the goal to listen with mongoose to changes made by another application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Mongo version is 3.6 or later, there is a possibility to listen the collection using [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I need. And I found out, that mongoose 5 will support it: http://thecodebarbarian.com/introducing-mongoose-5.html#change-streams